# Pass HiddenFor ID from View to a another ActionResult which is a PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

My title I think is a little confusing, let me explain:

I have an `IndexView` where I display all the Jobs of Companies and I am trying to add a `PartialView` with the coresponding Image.

I do not want to save the Image on the JobTable when I submit a Job. I want Images to be separate and linked only by `UserID`. In the page details I had an `int? ID` in the `ActionResult` header, I made two `LINQ` queries, first selects `UserID` with the `int? ID`, in second query I selected the ImageID with UserID from first query so I am trying to do the same but here I have no ID in URL because I display a list.

Since this is a list I tried to get the value from each `@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ID)` which is inside a foreach but I couldn't pass it back to my ActionResult (which is `PartialView` not Index), I tried with `ViewBag`, `Sessions` everything is null everytime. I gave it a `name`, a `Value`(uppercase and lowercase) with `@` and without.

Here code:

```
    public ActionResult ImgPanel(Job job, int? ID) 
    {
        var JobUserID = (from j in db.Jobs
                        where j.ID == ID /*Here should be the ID from the View of each job object*/
                        select j.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

        var img = (from j in db.Images
                    where j.UserID == JobUserID
                    select j).ToList();

        return View(img);          

    }
```

Well the ActionResult for ImgPanel in this state returns an Image, but only first(in all Jobs same Image), the second time my breakpoints are telling me only null on everything.

View Code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{      
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ID) /*I removed all tries with name Value Viewbags etc*/
    @Html.Action("ImgPanel", "Jobs") /*Here I call the PartialView ImgPanel*/
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationUsers.CompName)</h3>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h4>                   
                    <h5><strong>Days Left: </strong>@Convert.ToInt32((item.DateExp - DateTime.Now).TotalDays)</h5>
                    <p>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Jobs", new { Id = item.ID})" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Details</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Bookmark</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Hide</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You need to show your view code (`@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ID)` could never work because that is obviously in a `foreach` loop which will not bind correctly (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for an explanation)

Comment: All you need is `@Html.Action("ImgPanel", "Jobs", new { id = item.ID })` (and you should remove the `Job job` parameter from the method

Comment: Omg man, how did I **MISEED** such a basic thing. I was so focused how do I get that `HiddenFor` that I wasted so much time on it, then I tried some akward things with `foreach` in ActionResult, that made no sense at all. I really have a problem with over thinking and missing the most easy things. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing in a viewmodel which contains your IDs.

In your view:

```
@Html.Action("ImgPanel", "Jobs", new MyViewModel() { ItemId = item.ID })
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult ImgPanel(MyViewModel viewmodel) 
{
    var JobUserID = (from j in db.Jobs
                    where j.ID == viewmodel.ItemId /*Here you use the ID stored in the viewmodel*/
                    select j.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

    var img = (from j in db.Images
                where j.UserID == JobUserID
                select j).ToList();

    return View(img);          

}
```

Hope that helps!